# Getting exception "ArrayOutOfBounds:1" though it is not accessing any indexout of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, exception, user-interface, stack-trace

Though this code was working fine when there was no GUI added. I am now getting the following exception. (I read the SCCE for such exceptions is posting the whole stacktrace and the code at the first line of the stack trace. I hope it is clear.)

**Error:**

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at generaterpt.TransactionDetails.ReadFromFile(TransactionDetails.java:90)
        at generaterpt.DMS.GenerateReport(DMS.java:25)
        at report.Monthly.genButtonActionPerformed(Monthly.java:95)
        at report.Monthly.access$000(Monthly.java:20)
        at report.Monthly$1.actionPerformed(Monthly.java:55)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

**Code:**

```
try
        {
        File file = new File("TransactionDetails.txt");

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String [] tokens = line.split(",");
                String [] modeltoken = tokens[0].split("=");
                String [] nametoken = tokens[1].split("=");
                String [] monthtoken = tokens[2].split("=");
                String [] yeartoken = tokens[3].split("=");


                String model = (""+modeltoken[1]);
}
```

error is at the last line.

Comment: And where is the proof that it wasn't accessing anything out of bounds?

Comment: Clearly, `modeltoken` is an array of less than two elements.

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: That uncompilable code snippet is no SSCCE.

Comment: @Andrew, so should I just remove the whole exception part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only line that you are accessing an element of the array is:

```
 String model = (""+modeltoken[1]);
```

Therefore, it can be assumed that modeltoken has less than 2 elements and that your data in the file has an error.

This would cause the exception. I would suggest you add error checking code:

```
String model = "No Data In File";

if(modeltoken.length < 2)
System.err.println("modeltoken has less than 2 elements. Size is:"+String.valueOf(smodeltoken.length));
else
model = (""+modeltoken[1]);
```

Comment: Extra: Do *NOT* use the `""+something` idiom, use `String.valueOf(something)` instead. Is faster, clearer, and uses less memory.

Comment: Oh my, thank you! There was an error in the file.
However, now I am getting some logical error that is passing null values to the file where im writing this token :(

Comment: @Basilisk Hi, I think you need to make a new question for a different error. Also, if question is solved good to accept an answer or add your own. Good luck!